# Import package in gremlin

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to import "https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/tinkerpop/io/graphson/TitanGraphSONModule.java" in gremlin by using command as

```
import https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/tinkerpop/io/graphson/TitanGraphSONModule.java;
```

But getting **error** like this:

> Invalid import definition: 'https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/tinkerpop/io/graphson/TitanGraphSONModule.java;'

How can I import this class - `TitanGraphSONModule.java`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just like a Java import:

```
gremlin> import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.TitanGraphSONModule
```