# JanusGraph output subgraph as GraphSON error

Tags: java, groovy, titan, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to output a subgraph as GraphSON in the Gremlin shell with JanusGraph.

TinkerPop documentation for reference:
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphson-reader-writer

When I write the full graph this works fine, however, when I want to write a subgraph that I've queried using these commands:

```
gremlin> subGraph = g.V(45240).repeat(__.bothE().subgraph('subGraph').bothV()).times(4).cap('subGraph').next()
```

I use the same write command:

```
gremlin> subGraph.io(IoCore.graphson()).writeGraph("45240_sub4.json")
```

I get this error:

> (was java.lang.IllegalStateException) (through reference chain: org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier["inVertexId"])

Searching around, I found another thread that said I needed to import a package in order to do this properly (for TitanGraph, but I figured it would apply to JanusGraph as well): [Import package in gremlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410543/import-package-in-gremlin)

However, whenever I try to import:

```
gremlin>  import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.TitanGraphSONModule
```

I get this error:

> Invalid import definition: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.TitanGraphSONModule'; reason: startup failed:
>   script1494618250861805544050.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.TitanGraphSONModule
>    @ line 1, column 1.
>      import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.TitanGraphSONModule
>      ^
>
> 1 error

How can I output a subgraph as a GraphSON in Gremlin shell using JanusGraph?

Answer (score 7):

When you use the `subgraph()` step, the result is a `TinkerGraph`, however its vertex and edge IDs are carried over from the `JanusGraph` instance. In particular, the edge IDs are of type `RelationIdentifier` which require JanusGraph's custom serializer `JanusGraphSONModule` to export cleanly.

Here is an example, based off a [previous example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/rPgXfRo2k4o/YxD3Jk9gBgAJ) from Titan, that you can run in the Gremlin Console:

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('inmemory')
graph.io(graphson()).readGraph('data/tinkerpop-modern.json')
g = graph.traversal()
subGraph = g.E().hasLabel('knows').subgraph('sg').cap('sg').next()
graphsonIO = IoCore.graphson().graph(subGraph).registry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.getInstance()).create()
graphsonIO.writeGraph('/tmp/subgraph.json')
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably just have to import the JanusGraph equivalent of that Titan module which should be: `org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.JanusGraphSONModule`

So, this import should work:

```
gremlin>  import org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.JanusGraphSONModule
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the import you suggested, but unfortunately I still get the same error as before: (was java.lang.IllegalStateException) (through reference chain: org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier["inVertexId"])

Comment: The answer from Jason Plurad is probably the right one. I just noticed that you are importing a Titan module although you are working with JanusGraph.